# ActiveX Combo box list filtered according to initial letter

Tags: excel, vba

I have a combo box that lists data from 2 columns, Surname and Christian name, that works well but it is a rather long list to scroll. What I want to achieve is to be able to enter or select the initial of a Surname and the Combo box dropdown list to only show both columns (as it does now) of Surnames beginning with that letter, or to open the full list with the first Surname of that letter selected. I have found lots of what appeared to be answers but either I didn't understand the answer or I couldn't get them to work. Thank you.

I already have a private sub for the combo box to give me a row number (thanks to norie for that) and get the 2 columns by setting ColumnCount to 2.

```
    Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Me.Range("G1").Value = ComboBox1.ListIndex + 3

End Sub
```

Comment: How are you populating the combobox?

Comment: Using ListFillRange that includes columns A & B

Comment: Columns A & B from which sheet?

Comment: From the sheet where all the data is stored 'Data!A3:B99'

Answer (score 0):

Combobox allows you to filter the items as you type by using the following code:

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Dim arrIn As Variant, arrOut As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    arrIn = Sheet1.Range("A2:A2000")

    ReDim arrOut(1 To UBound(arrIn), 1 To 1)

    For i = 1 To UBound(arrIn)
        If arrIn(i, 1) Like ComboBox1.Text & "*" Then
            j = j + 1
            arrOut(j, 1) = arrIn(i, 1)
        End If
    Next
    ComboBox1.List = arrOut
End Sub
```

Comment: Not if you've populated the combobox from a range via ListFillRange.

Comment: Thanks Gangula for such a rapid reply. I have tried it and it works, but ComboBox1.List = arrOut gives me a runtime error.

Comment: If I comment that line out it still works OK. Thanks

Comment: Have handed a working copy over to the person who I was doing it for, will get an update on it on Thursday when I'm next in as a volunteer cooking for the charity organisation he works for.